# Create a copy of an object rather that reinitialising inside of a new multiprocessing process

Tags: python, copy, multiprocessing, deep-copy

This code shows the structure of what I am trying to do.

```
import multiprocessing
from foo import really_expensive_to_compute_object

## Create a really complicated object that is *hard* to initialise.
T = really_expensive_to_compute_object(10) 

def f(x):
  return T.cheap_calculation(x)

P = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=64)
results = P.map(f, range(1000000))

print results
```

The problem is that each process starts by spending a lot of time recalculating T instead of using the original T that was computed once. Is there a way to prevent this? T has a fast (deep) copy method, so can I get Python to use that instead of recalculating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have `f` take a `T` parameter instead of referencing the global, and do the copies yourself?

```
import multiprocessing, copy
from foo import really_expensive_to_compute_object

## Create a really complicated object that is *hard* to initialise.
T = really_expensive_to_compute_object(10) 

def f(t, x):
  return t.cheap_calculation(x)

P = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=64)
results = P.map(f, (copy.deepcopy(T) for _ in range(1000000)), range(1000000))

print results
```

Answer (score 2):

[`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) documentation [suggests](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms)

> Explicitly pass resources to child processes

So your code can be rewritenn to something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import functools

class really_expensive_to_compute_object(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print 'expensive creation'
        time.sleep(3)

    def cheap_calculation(self, x):
        return x * 2

def f(T, x):
    return T.cheap_calculation(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## Create a really complicated object that is *hard* to initialise.
    T = really_expensive_to_compute_object(10)
    ## helper, to pass expensive object to function
    f_helper = functools.partial(f, T)
    # i've reduced count for tests 
    P = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    results = P.map(f_helper, range(100))

    print results
```